# USB-C Splitter for Audio

Tags: usb, headphones, earphones

I've searched far & wide and I can only assume there is nothing or it's impossible.

Is there such thing as a USB-C splitter that two USB-C earphones/headphones can connect to, that then connects to a computer via USB-A? so two people can listen to the same audio?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the type of splitter you are asking for exists.

USB-C Headphones contain an integrated DAC, which means the audio is sent to the headphones from your computer/phone over the USB protocol. You may already know that USB cannot be "split" like a headphone jack can, but you can use a USB hub to allow more than one USB device to be plugged into a single USB port.

You should be able to get both headphones to appear as separate sound devices on your computer if they are both plugged into a hub or separate USB ports. From there it will take some [additional software](https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/index.htm) to play audio to both devices at the same time.

One more caveat is that your computer is going to need a USB-C port or a very particular USB-A (3.1) port in order to support hubs with USB-C ports themselves.